# How does a discharged capacitor work when a dc passes through?

Tags: capacitor, dc

First of all, I'm sorry for bad English.
My question is if a DC current passes through a DISCHARGED capacitor, what happens? How about a CHARGED capacitor?
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Think of electricity like water and think of a capacitor like a tub of water that holds water. What happens if you try to give a tub full of water more water (assume the tub is able to contain all the water inside of a container or something)? What happens if you try to give a tub more water that is already emptying water?

Comment: the rate of change of voltage equals the Current/Capacitance or dV/dt=Ic/C  [V/s=A/F]

Comment: @KingDuken doesn't work.  Send a reverse current through a charged capacitor and it empties.  (Charge and energy are two different things, like water and P.E.)  The joules are always positive, but the coulombs can be pos or neg.  Add ANTI-WATER to an empty bathtub and you increase the energy, but add it to a water-filled bathtub and you decrease the energy.  OP's question isn't trivial.

Comment: @Bort of course DC passes through capacitors.  Maxwell's central discovery was based on this concept.  Engineering equations rely on current *through* capacitors.  And, with most modern capacitors, the current in the dielectric is 99.99% electron-motion (not Maxwell's Displacement Current.)  Current in dielectric equals current in the capacitor terminals.

Comment: @Bort Do you mean a DISCHARGED capacitor doesn't change while the dc wires connect to 2 its pole?

Comment: @KingDuken for the first case. apparently, we cannot add more water, but for second, maybe i didn't understand you properly, if I am right, yes we can add more water until completing tube. But what do you mean by second question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental equation for an ideal capactitor is.

$$i = c\frac{dv}{dt}$$

Lets rearrange that a bit and integrate it.

$$\frac{i}{c} = \frac{dv}{dt}$$

$$\int_0^t\frac{i}{c}dt = \int_0^t\frac{dv}{dt}dt = v -v_0$$

$$v = \int_0^t\frac{i}{c}dt + v_0$$

(where \$v_0\$ is the voltage at time 0)

So lets think about a few scenarios.

## Scenario 1: we pass a constant DC current through the capacitor.

$$v=\frac{i}{c}t + v_0$$

The voltage accross our capacitor increasaes linerarly without limit.

## Scenario 2: we connect the capacitor to an idealised voltage source at time t=0

Now we have a problem. We have a step-change in v which makes \$\frac{dv}{dt}\$ infinite. That in turn leads to infinite current.

---

Clearly neither of these situations is physically plausible. We cannot have infinite currents and we cannot have voltages that grow without limit. In reality something else must limit the voltage and/or current. Maybe that is parasitic resistances and inductances, maybe it is current limits of your power supply, maybe it is the capacitor going up in smoke and ceasing to behave like a capacitor.

This demonstrates that idealised models can only take us so far. Sometimes the idealised models will show up results that make no physitcal sense.

So lets consider a slightly more realistic scenario.

## At time t=0 we take a discharged capacitor and connect it to a supply that delivers a current of I if the voltage is less than V and a voltage of V if the current is less than I.

We now have a situation with three sections. Before connection the capacitor is discharged. Upon connection it starts charging linerarly, the voltage rises until it reaches V. The power supply then reaches it's voltage limit and the charging stops.

Comment: Yes, this is an answer I can agree with. If I could upvote your answer twice I would.

Answer (score 3):

Q = CV is the basic formula for a capacitor and applies always.

Rate of change of Q (charge) is current so: -

I = C dv/dt

If you inject 1 amp into a 1 farad capacitor the voltage rises at 1 volt per second. It has to. If you pull 1 amp from the same capacitor the voltage falls at 1 volt per second.

Answer (score 0):

As charge enters one side, one plate, of the capacitor, the internal polarizable molecules in the capacitor's insulating dielectric rotate and warp and transfer the **opposite** charge to the other plate of the capacitor.

That charge, converted into electrons, either moves in or out, depending on the new charge polarity.

Comment: ok. and if AC current passes through a CHARGED capacitor, it blocks the AC?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf if cap has vacuum instead insulation, it's ether particles :D

Comment: Thanks again for all replies. I Concluded: When a DISCHARGED capacitor directly connects to DC (Constant Voltage Source with verifiable Current) for few times there will be a Potential Difference (Voltage) on to plates and a very few current amount is drawn from Source This process is kind of CHARGING of the cap (of course not safe) During this process, Potential Difference of two plates reaches to DC Source Voltage value Then the cap itself blocks the DC current coming from the source and no current will be in the circuit. for some low capacitance caps the collapse of the Dielectric can occur

Answer (score 0):

If an object has more electrons than protons, it is said to be negatively charged and will generally try to push nearby electrons away from it.  Conversely, if it has fewer electrons than protons, it is positively charged and will attract nearby electrons.  Normally this would mean that if one tried to move very many electrons from one object to another, it would become increasingly difficult as the recipient of the electrons would generate a stronger and stronger negative field "trying" to push electrons away, while the donor would generate a stronger and stronger positive field "trying" to prevent electrons from leaving.

If one attaches electrodes to a pair of plates that are close together, however, and electrons are taken from one plate and added to the other, the plate to which electrons had been added will push away nearby electrons on the other plate, thus pushing them toward the attached electrode.  Meanwhile, the plate from which electrons had been removed will draw electrons on the other plate toward it and away from that plate's electrode.  The net effect will be that the electrode attached to the negative plate with excess electrons won't push away new electrons nearly as strongly as it would in the absence of the positive plate, and the positive plate won't resist loss of electrons nearly as strongly as it would in the absence of the negative plate.  Note that the closer the plates are together, the stronger this effect will be, but that if the plates are too strong electrons will simply jump from the negative plate to the positive one.

Certain materials allow electrons a certain amount of mobility within them, but don't allow electrons to be added or removed.  Placing such a material, called a dielectric, between two plates will enhance interaction of the charges on them.  Even with a good dielectric, the amount of energy required to move each electron from the positive plate to the negative plate will increase as more electrons are moved, but but the rate at which this occurs will be much slower than it would be otherwise.

Answer (score -3):

DC does not "pass through" the cap. It charges a discharged cap. There will be a short pulse on the output side as the cap charges, the length of which is determined by the RC time constant.

It does nothing to a charged cap.

Edit: I see the issue some have taken with my answer here - Yes, **during the charge time** DC current is passing through the cap. Charge time is determined by the RC time constant, barring any current limiting in the power supply that may be unrelated to the power supply's ESR. Once the voltage on across cap equals the DC voltage applied, the DC current will be 0, (ignoring any leakage current).

Comment: It's not always RC. In fact in most cases today it's power supply current limits that defines how much time the capacitor is charged.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. So you say that 

1. A charged capacitor doesn't pass dc. In other words, it blocks the DC and short circuit does not happen.

2. A discharged capacitor will charge while passing DC through.

Am I right? 

[![Image][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WKIO.png

Comment: It's not DC when it's charging... It's DC when things are stable- i  steady state. After infinite time. Before that it's called transition effects. Or not, it's a translation from language i learned...

Comment: Gregory - its still RC, its just that a portion of the "R" is the internal resistance of the power source itself.

Comment: However you tell me that A DC or Near DC current will charge the capacitor if it is uncharged and then it blocks DC?

Comment: @norm it can be a closed loop current control

Comment: ok. and if AC current passes through a CHARGED capacitor, it blocks the AC?

Comment: @abbasmolaei capacitor only blocks DC. AC is characterised by frequency. How well it passes is calculated by impedance: Z = 1/j2piFC

Comment: DC certainly does pass through capacitors.  Play with a 2000 farad cap, you'll figure it out.  The correct statement is: constant current *through* the capacitor causes the voltage across the plates to rise continuously.  A basic engineering concept.  (See also "Lies to Children."   It's a lie-to-children when we say that capacitors cannot pass DC.  It's a wrong idea, but somewhat OK to tell little kids.  Engineers know better.)

Comment: @wbeaty i apologize but what do you mean by "constant current "? Did you mean "constant voltage current" or "constant current but variable voltage."? I'm sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @AbbasMolaei   constant amperes, such as one milliamp.  Voltage can vary.  (Two basic, simplified types of power supplies exist:  constant voltage source, such as a battery, and constant current source, such as LED drivers, transistor collector terminals, VandeGraaff generators, etc.)  With CV the voltage is fixed and the current varies.  With CC the current is fixed and the voltage varies.  Connect a CV source to a capacitor and you'll get infinite current.

Comment: @wbeaty OK. Thanks. Then you say if we apply CC to 2 plates of a cap (no matter Charged or Discharged cap), and at the same time if we measure the potential difference (voltage) of this two plates, that increases continuously. But if the power supply is CV type and we place a light bulb after cap in the picture above (again no matter Charged or Discharged cap), the light bulb is off. Right?

Comment: "Connect a CV source to a capacitor and you'll get infinite current" ??? You sure about that?

Comment: @AbbasMolaei no, if the capacitor was discharged, then the light bulb will initially light to full brightness.  Then it will grow dimmer, at a rate depending on the capacitance and the R(bulb.)   For example, use a 100-ohm bulb and a 3300-farad ultra-capacitor, and the bulb will still glow at full brightness for many, many minutes (since RC is 92 hours!)

Comment: @Norm if the current wasn't infinite, then it must not have been a CV source!  Make sure to use zero-ohm resistors.

Comment: @wbeaty - maybe with theoretical perfect components. Reality is quite different. Wires all have resistance. Power supplies (even CV supplies) have output resistance. Even the cap has internal resistance. Every CV power supply I have ever worked on has had caps across the output for filtering.

Comment: @Norm Again, if the current wasn't infinite, then we must not have been using zero-ohm resistors (ideal resistors, ideal wires, etc.)  To get real results we must replace the above schematic's ideal capacitor with a full capacitor model, parasitic inductances as well as metal and dielectric resistances.  If not, then idealized components assumed as usual, infinite currents will result.  Large hint supplied: "make sure to use zero-ohm resistors!"  :)

Comment: @wbeaty - Ideal components do not exist. Why even bring them into it? It simply confuses OP. He wants to know "What happens" - that implies "real results", not theoretical ideal performance.

Comment: @Norm That's exactly his/her point, it isn't a constant voltage source because the voltage is not constant.

Comment: @Norm real components and their many hidden RLC elements are extremely confusing.  (Clearly a real capacitor circuit is confusing the OP.) That's why ideal components are used in all classroom instruction, textbook explanations, engineering equations: perfect resistors, zero-ohm wires, capacitors with zero losses.  OP's questions are answered by theoretical ideal performance: replace their capacitor with a full model, constructed entirely from ideal components.  Milliohm (ideal) resistors placed in the (ideal) capacitor's terminals to start.

Comment: As Peter Green explained in his answer below - Ideal Components can lead to implausible results if one is not careful.